# Can function arguments be passed into a string?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm making a calculator table with javascript, and I'm writing `document.getElementById('x').innerHTML` all the time. Can I write a function to replace this code? For example:

```
function select (a) {
  return document.getElementById(${a}).innerHTML;
}
```

The trouble I see is if I used template literals within `getElementById`, I can't add the quotes necessary to define the string as a string.

To put it back into context, I have many cells in a table each with different Ids. In order to allow js to update each cell, I've had to repeatedly write: `document.getElementById('x').innerHTML`. This had me wonder, can I just write a little function that would let me skip this extra typing? Can a function take an argument and return it with quotes around it?

Comment: *"I have many cells in a table each with different Ids."* That's usually avoidable.

Comment: The reason they're there is to allow for different calculations in each cell, using variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

```
var select = function(a) {
  return document.getElementById(a).innerHTML;
}
var ham = select('thing');
```

is good enough.  The system already knows there's a string there, because that's the type it is when you call the `select()` function.

---

If you're trying to make for less typing while assigning a value to the `innerHTML`, you have to do that within the function body as well.  Why?  Because once you return the innerHTML string property from the function it's an immutable value, similar to saying `'a' = 'b'`.

Here's what that assignment function might look like:

```
var assign = function( target, value) {
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = value;
}
assign('capitalGain', '$' + currency(initialGain));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Paul. I tried: `var select = function (a) {
  return document.getElementById(a).innerHTML;
}` and then later tried to use it with: `select('capitalGain') = "$" +  currency(initialGain);` only to get the error `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`

Comment: Oh! You're trying to do an assignment, not a fetch.  That's a very different thing.  Try `function(assignto, value) { document.getElementById(assignto).innerHTML = value }`

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work either. What's on the right hand side of the above assignment is irrelevant to this issue. I'm wondering if it's possible to create a function that takes an argument and passes it as a string, with the requirements that `getElementById` require, which is that the string is contained within quotes. In other words, a function that takes the argument `a` and returns `document.getElementById('a').innerHTML`

Comment: No, it's perfectly relevant, because you're trying to make an assignment.  You can't make an assignment to the return value of a function that is itself an immutable string.

Comment: You're trying to treat the `innerHTML` property as a pointer (as if it were C).  That's not how it works.

Comment: I see, so the closest you can get is by writing `function select (a) {
  return document.getElementById(a);
}` and then using it later as `select('idNameHere').innerHTML = ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194970/discussion-between-willbeing-and-paulprogrammer).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need template literals for a task this simple:

```
function select(a) {
    return document.getElementById(a).innerHTML;
}
```

Or if you must:

```
function select(a) {
    return document.getElementById(`${a}`).innerHTML;
}
```

And now Chrome supports a jQuery-like syntax - so in new versions of Chrome, this will also work.

```
function select(a) {
    return $(`#${a}`)[0].innerHTML;
}
```

Or the more verbose and understandable version:

```
function select(a) {
    let str = "#" + a;
    let [elem] = $(str);
    return elem.innerHTML;
}
```

And one more - in contrast to the verbose one, this one is quite unreadable and bad practice.

```
const select = a => ([{ innerHTML: b }] = $(`#${a}`), b);
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, but your first answer, the simplest, is the first thing I tried. It doesn't work, because `getElementById` requires quotes within the parenthesis to define the id

Comment: @willBeing the `getElementById` function requires a string parameter.  When you write javascript, values in quotes are considered strings.  But so are variables that have a string value.